# .htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory or to file depending on path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I navigate to `sub.domain.com/path` it gets me to `domain.com/site.php?site=sub&page=path`.

When `path` is something like `text.text` I want to point it to `domain.com/subdomains/sub/text.text` but I can't get it work together.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*\..*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.php?site=%1&page=$1 [L]
```

When `path` contains `text.text` apply this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [P,L,NC,QSA]
```

Also how can I make the rule above work with relative path (without `http://domain.com/`)?

Update:

```
sub.domain.com -> site.php?site=sub
sub.domain.com/path -> site.php?site=sub&page=path
sub.domain.com/path.ext -> subdomains/sub/path.ext
```

All above works, just one more left:

```
sub.domain.com/constant/text.text -> constant/text.text
```

That one above should apply only if after constant is some text with dot. If not this rule should apply:

```
sub.domain.com/path -> site.php?site=sub&page=path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(constant|site\.php$) - [L,NC]

# path with no dot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ site.php?site=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ site.php?site=%1&page=$1 [L,QSA]

# anything else i.e. path with dot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [P,L,NC]
```

Comment: sub.domain.com/path points to  /subdomains/sub/site.php (should point to /site.php). Could you please fix that?

Comment: Just one more problem. When path is empty (sub.domain.com) it points to /subdomains/sub/index.html. Could you please change it to point site.php as well?

Comment: I forgot about one important thing. When url is like sub.domain.com/constant/sometext.sometext (/constant/ at the begining and sometext with dot) it should not apply any rules. If you could help me with that last one i would be so grateful.

Comment: First rule is ignore rule and that will execute for any domain. This is actually side effect of answering a problem via comments. Better to capture all the requirements in question itself..

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying my question properly and thank you for your patience. I've updated my question. Please take a look at it i you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do both in one rule, use two. Also it doesn't make since to use the Proxy flag if you want to use a relative URL providing your subfolder subdomains is in the root.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*\..*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.php?site=%1&page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*\..*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: There is some loop in redirect path: You don't have permission to access /sites//sites//sites//sites//sites//sites//sites//sites//sites//site.php/site.php/sites/site.php/site.php/sites/sites/site.php/site.php/sites/site.php/site.php...

Comment: Ok I made an update to the rules and try adding the rewritebase as well.